# What is the difference between "User Control" and "Page" in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I am really new to Silverlight. I am working through some of the sample codes I found online.

I notices sometimes a new "Page" is added, and sometimes a new "User Control" is added.What are the differences between those 2?

Btw, when I tried specifying the URL for a hyperlink as "www.apple.com", there is an error saying "www.apple.com" can not be found. Are there anyway of specifying an URL for a website for a HyperlinkButton?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SL3 and up; a `Page` correlates to the Navigation framework whereas a `UserControl` is a control providing a defined set of functionality using multiple controls which can then be used within a `Page`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So a page has to be created first, and then a usercontrol can be created for the page. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks :) How does the child window compare to them? Is a window more like a mini page or so? Thanks :)

Comment: The Window class only exists within an OOB SL application; otherwise you should only be using the Page class. A child window is a concept rather then an implementation.

Comment: @aaron checl out the toolkit, there is an implementation of ChildWindow. http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html. @Rosie, child window basically a popup, see the samples linked.

Answer (score 0):

User Control:

When you build your project , any user control that you created will appear in the toolbox also.   You can drag and drop it like any other control (like a button or a grid).User controls are used for enhanced flexibility. You can customize your controls, set as many properties you want , and it really simplifies things without going for creating custom controls.

Page:

However, when you come to a Page, you can use it mostly for Navigation . It can contain other controls , but it is mainly intended for Navigation within Frames.